# Applications disappear from Gnome Panel after cloning to machines with the same hardware

Tags: 10.10, clone

I have cloned Ubuntu installation to multiple machines by following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5938/how-can-i-do-mass-installs-on-multiple-computers). The cloning works well. But if there are some custom installed apps in the originally installed machine, after cloning the clones don't show up custom apps in the gnome panel. I have partly solved the problem by booting into recovery mode and selecting 'repair broken packages' But I have a slow internet connection and it takes very long time on each machine. Another solution was to create shortcuts for those apps on the desktop on the original machine, which also appear on the cloned machines. Is there any way to make cloned machines show all the apps in the gnome panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is the possibility of the folder /usr/share/applications and $HOME/.local/share/applications out of sync. That two folders are used to place 'launcher.desktop' of all the applications you install.
first of all try to compare both the folder:

1.get local dir1 md5sum

> cd /usr/share/applications find . -type f -exec md5sum {} ; |sort -k2 > dir1_md5

Sample export :

c6d19fc12bbba3ba5844e9d228c10daa *./INPUT_FILE.txt

2.get remote servers dir2 md5sum

> ssh username@servername "cd /usr/share/applications; find . -type f -exec md5sum {} " ; |sort -k2 > dir2_md5

3.compare :

> diff dir1_md5 dir2_md5

Dont forget for $HOME/.local/share/applications to, just simply change the command /usr/share/applications with  $HOME/.local/share/applications.

If there is a different, and if you do not want to bother with the difference. simply copy and paste all the contents of the folder /usr/share/applications and $HOME/.local/applications to the target machine.

Other command to compare is :

> ls -a /usr/share/applications  > dir1_md5
>
> ssh username@servername "ls -a /usr/share/applications" > dir2_md5
>
> diff dir1_md5 dir2_md5

but, this command  just compare the list of folders, not to difference the contents of the launcher

Comment: Just as a heads-up, please don't use quotes for code. Insteal, put 4 spaces before the code , which is on a separate line.