# Videos pause automatically

Tags: video, codecs, video-player

I installed Ubuntu on multiple computers by following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5938/how-can-i-do-mass-installs-on-multiple-computers) . Now many of my users complain that while playing video (xvid or mp4), after few minutes videos go into a paused state, and only resume playing if the mouse cursor is moved.

It happens on vlc and movie player as well. I have installed codecs from the mediubuntu repository. The systems are fully updated.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the screen saver ? Since it happens a few minutes after starting and resumes with the mouse it is likely to be screensaver related...

Comment: Yes I did, and didn't work.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Ubuntu failed in many ways on my users Dell vostro laptops. So all of them have gone for Windows now.