# Best Way To Mass Install Ubuntu 12.10 over 1000 PC

Tags: system-installation

My work require to mass install Ubuntu 12.10 on huge load of PC.I have been searching the internet for the past 5 days with no success.Please help me if anyone has experience about this.

Comment: This is probably what you're looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5938/how-can-i-do-mass-installs-on-multiple-computers

Comment: I think you will run in problems while cloning the machines via rsync as shown in the other thread.

Answer (score 3):

Install Ubuntu via PXE Boot and take the configuration from a preseed file. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/preseed-intro.html

You need a TFTP-, DHCP-, NFS- and a Webserver, which can be one machine in your local network. After the full configuration, you will have an unattended install of ubuntu.

If you need further configuration on all the pc you can use puppet to provide the same configuration to all machines.
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/puppet.html

This is a lot of configuration bevor the installation, but it is less work then installing every pc by hand.

Another option is to create an image of your customized Ubuntu an share it via multicast with clonezilla: http://www.corbacho.info/clonezilla/clonezilla.html

Further configurations can be done with puppet again.